# Is there a way to get a named key/value from SUBARRAY without knowing the main key?

Tags: php, sub-array

**Short:** Is there a way to get a named key/value from SUBARRAY without knowing the main key ?

**Long:**

Ive got a foreach loop that extracts text-files & turns them into individual / single arrays (resetting the array between each file)...

example:

```
Array
(
    [Blah Blah] => Array
        (
            [number] => 10
            [name] => nameBlah
            [image] => 
        )
)


Array
(
    [pinkblue597] => Array
        (
            [number] => 18
            [name] => nameBlah68
            [image] => 
        )
)
```

(the 1st part to turn into array is used by multiple parts of a process so I dont want to add unnecessary code)

I want to extract the value of "name" and "number", however I do not know the value / format of the key in advance.. - Example: pinkblue597

If I do `print_r`, I do see the array as I want...

```
print_r($found,true)."\n";
```

but if I do this, `$name=$found[0];` I get no results for "$name"...

or

if I do this, `$name=$found[0]["name"];`  I get no results for "$name"...

I could do this via a foreach loop, but it seems inefficient...

PS there will only be ONE (unknown) key in this array, & a sub-array. The sub array is always the same.

Edited: made the code easier to see (forgot to do this)

Comment: You can use `array_keys()`, so you can access your array with a numeric key.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center so that your question doesn't get down voted any further. One of your key problems here is that the example arrays you provide (_aside from not being properly formatted as code_) don't demonstrate the actual problem you're trying to solve. As such there is no reasonable way of deducing what you actually expect from what you have.

Comment: Some suggestions to improve your question would be to use something like [`var_export()`](http://php.net/var-export) instead of `print_r()` to provide, minimal, complete, and verifiable examples of your arrays and what you expect out of them. Since `var_export` will return actual valid PHP code instead of some arbitrary textual representation of data.

Comment: what makes you think `foreach` is inefficient?

Answer (score 1):

### If the array formation is going to be the same all the time...

then a (nested) `foreach` loop **will** suffice, take the example below,

```
<?php

$a = [
    'somethingUnknown13582563' => [
        'name' => 'name',
        'number' => 15
    ],

    'somethingUnknown2' => [
        'name' => 'another name',
        'number' => 24
    ]
];

foreach ($a as $key => $subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $subKey => $value) {
        echo $subArray[$subKey] . '<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

**Output**

```
name
15
another name
24
```

### Or...

You could use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php),

```
<?php

$a = [
    'somethingUnknown13582563' => [
        'name' => 'first name',
        'number' => 15
    ],

    'somethingUnknown2' => [
        'name' => 'name',
        'number' => 24
    ]
];

$a = array_values($a);

echo $a[0]['name'];

?>
```

Which would turn the first associative array in to numeric indexes and would like so,

```
array(
      0 => array(
             'name' => 'first name', 
             'number' => 15, 
           ), 
      1 => array(
             'name' => 'name', 
             'number' => 24, 
           )
)
```

Comment: Notice they're not saying there are two arrays nested in one array. They're saying there are two arrays that are each multidimensional, but contain only one element. So `$a1 = [['name' => 'foo']]; $a2 = [['name' => 'bar']];` and not `$a = [['name' => 'foo'],['name' => 'bar']]`

Comment: no problem, but also consider that their voiced concern is around foreach and efficiency which (_while it's not necessarily inefficient_) using `array_values` isn't going to be any better anyway. I think their primary concern is in just dereferencing the array easily.

Comment: `$subArray[$subKey]` is more simply written/accessed as `$value`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're creating a nested array in the first place if you only intend to discard it immediately, but since the array only appears to have a single element, and you only care about that element, you can simple use [`array_pop`](http://php.net/array-pop)

```
$a = [
    'somethingUnknown13582563' => [
        'name' => 'first name',
        'number' => 15
    ],
];

$data = array_pop($a);
echo $data['name']; // gives you 'first name'
```

*Note that `array_pop` is destructive. So if you don't want this behavior you could use something like [`end`](http://php.net/end) instead.*

```
$data = end($a); // same effect as array_pop but non-destructive
echo $data['name']; // also gives you 'first name'
```

With that said, the `foreach` construct isn't necessarily *inefficient*. I believe your true concern is around finding a simpler way to **dereference** the nested array. The easiest way to do that in your case is going to be using something like `end($a)['name']` which gives you the kind of straight-forward dereferencing you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to achieve this...

array_map — Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays. This will loop all the array elements through callback function and you can print each element present in the sub array..

```
<?php 
$myArry = array(
              'Blah Blah' => array(
                     'number' => 10, 
                     'name' => 'Blah Blah 1', 
                   ), 
              'pinkblue597' => array(
                     'number' => 15, 
                     'name' => 'Blah Blah 2', 
                   )
        );

array_map(function($arr){ 
    echo 'Name : '.$arr['name'].'<br>'; 
    echo 'Number : '.$arr['number'].'<br>';     
},$myArry);

?>
```

This will give you :

```
Name : Blah Blah 1
Number : 10
Name : Blah Blah 2
Number : 15
```